# How should I update a page column in SharePoint via Rest Api in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint, rest, power-automate

I would like to update a page column via Rest Api in Power Automate but I couldn't achieve my target. It is possible to update a list column via **"_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{fileUrl}')/ListItemAllFields"** uri I know but how does it work for page columns, do you have any idea for that?

[a screenshot which columns will be updated via Rest Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcZ20.png)

Thanks in advance,
Fatih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we could update column value in page using `/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{fileUrl}')/ListItemAllFields`

Below is my demo :

```
post /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Pages/page1.aspx')/ListItemAllFields
```

body:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.PagesItem"
  },
  "Title": "new Title"
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael Han_MSFT,

Thanks for your help, it was super useful.

After changing the body as below of your demo, it worked and solved my problem.

Body:
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.SitePagesItem"
  },
  "Title": "new Title"

}

Thanks a lot 
Fatih